# Is there a "regex" operator in MongoDB? (not "$regex")

Tags: php, regex, mongodb, yii2

I'm in a [discussion](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/issues/19) with one of Yii2's developers about a regex issue I believe I found. The developer insists that the framework is passing all unit tests, but every time I try to run a query with a regex in it, I see this being ran in my MongoDB:

```
find({
    "ns":"todevise.category",
    "limit":0,
    "batchSize":0,
    "skip":0,
    "flags":0,
    "query":{
        "path":{
            "regex":"^/30000", // <---- issue?
            "flags":""
        }
    },
    "fields":{
        "short_id":true,
        "path":true
    },
    "started_iterating":false
})
```

Which I believe is not a valid MongoDB query as I can't find any documentation about `regex` operator. (Not to be confused with the `$regex` operator, anyways).

So, my question is: Is that query a valid MongoDB query? And if "yes", what is the difference between `regex` and `$regex` operators?

Comment: Even if there was such am operator, how would it be distinguished with regular keys? The only possible option is that the `regex` is just a key, maybe that is the case?

Comment: @n9code No, the framework is actually outputting `regex` as if it was the `$regex` operator.

Comment: can you try to create a document with a key named `regex`?

Comment: Sure. What should I set it's value to? Also, what should I be looking for in the result (if any)? @n9code

Comment: The value does not matter, but let's try "Some Value", and then run a query like in your question with `"regex": "^Some.*"`, and let's see what happens.

Comment: No results from the query @n9code

Comment: Hmm..interesting. And what about `"regex": "Some Value"`? If this returns the document, then I guess there is certainly an issue. I mean, have you tried any example that processed the `regex`?

Comment: @n9code The main issue is that `regex` just isn't an operator. `$regex` is thou. And I'm not really sure how or why Yii2's unit tests are passing this one.

Comment: @n9code Tbh, I'm not even sure if they pass that part :/

Answer (score 1):

I belive that

```
{
  "regex":"^/30000", // <---- issue?
  "flags":"
}
```

is json object and both `regex` and `$regex` are keys of hash. But `$regex` is resreved keyword and recognized as operator that used to build query with condition. `regex` key in this case just ignored I guess.

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
      'path' => ['$regex'=> "^/30000"],
    ]);
```